# Finding the minimum of mapped data

Tags: ruby, dictionary

Given an array of complex objects, an algorithm for mapping each to Comparable values, and the desire to find the minimum such value, is there **a *built-in* library method** that will do this in a single pass?

Effective but not *perfectly* efficient solutions:

```
# Iterates through the array twice
min = objects.map{ |o| make_number o }.min

# Calls make_number one time more than is necessary
min = make_number( objects.min_by{ |o| make_number o } )
```

Efficient, but verbose solution:

```
min = nil
objects.each{ |o| n=make_number(o); min=n if !min || n<min }
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min

Comment: Your second "inefficient" solution seems good enough to me. It doesn't call `make_number` one more time per pass; it literally calls it one extra time at the end. That doesn't seem like an efficiency problem, but a perfectionist one.

Comment: Does the time taken by _min_ over the temporary array matter?  On my box, _min_ of an array of 1M random integers takes 97 msec.  That's 97 ns / entry.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to microoptimize. As @Darshan points out, one of my solutions is O(N) vs O(N+1)==O(N). I've bolded the important part of the question above: "Is there a method that already does this?" Just as `group_by` and `min_by` do some great work that many people would naively do on their own, I was asking if there was a simple built-in way to do this. Looks like the answer is "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, no such library method already exists.**

I don't really see an issue with either of your two original solutions. The enumerator code is written in C and is generally very fast. You can always just benchmark it and see what is fastest for your specific dataset and code (try https://github.com/acangiano/ruby-benchmark-suite)

However, if you really do want one pass, you can simplify your `#each` version by using `#reduce`:

```
min = objects.reduce(Float::INFINITY){ |min, o|
  n = make_number(o)
  min > n ? n : min
}
```

If your objects are already numbers of some form, you can omit the `Float::INFINITY`. Otherwise, in order to make sure we are only comparing number values, you will need to add it.

Comment: Having `Float::INFINITY` here is pointless. Omitting this argument will simply use the first item in the array, which will be good enough.

Comment: Could be a one-liner with `objects.reduce(Float::INFINITY){ |min, o| [min, make_number(o)].min }`

Comment: @Baldrick That creates N temporary arrays just to do a simple comparison, and also has the overhead of a method call.

Comment: I think `Float::INFINITY` is needed, otherwise you can get the first value as minimum, whereas we're looking for the minimum of a `make_number` operation.

Comment: @tadman and @baldrick it will all depend on what `o` is and if it has `>` defined. Updated the answer with this note.

Comment: Due to the `make_number` conversion, right. That does make it a little unconventional. `nil` might be a better thing to put in there, so you don't get `Float::INFINITY` for an empty array, which is a very odd "minimum" to return.

Comment: @tadman `nil` won't work: `nil > 1 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method >' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I know, that's why you'd have to `min ||= n` before doing any comparisons, or add in an `if (min)` test.